# What is website industry benchmark for Net Promoter Score?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, data-analysis, nps

Industry benchmarks do exists for Net Promoter Scores. For example, the Consumer Software Industry (Sauro, 2011) has an average Net Promoter score of 21%--meaning a 20% is about average for products like Quicken, QuickBooks, Excel, Photoshop and iTunes. I have two questions for you.

**Question 1:** What is the NPS benchmark for websites?

**Question 2:** Have you ever used NPS in your usability studies and what has been your benchmark or cutoff value? How do you interpret it?

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: Possible duplicates:

  (1) http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63599/which-parts-of-the-overall-user-experience-is-best-represented-by-the-nps
  (2) http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57987/alternative-questions-to-the-net-promoter-score

Comment: Long story short, you probably talk about the SUS.

http://www.measuringu.com/sus.php

Comment: NPS is based on the following question "How likely are you to recommend this product to somebody?" This is too much of a general "gut feel" measure to be of any use for improving user experience. And thus is never used in usability testing. It was a buzz word for marketers a few years back. People haven't really figured out what else can be done afterwards and some companies have stopped using it because of this.

Comment: @nightning that's not really the case. It's a general indicator that still has broad use. WoMI is more recent, but similar and equally effective. Satisfaction index is another alternative. All useful, all require additional probing questions to fill out the picture.

Comment: @plainclothes Sure NPS is well promoted and is still used, however there's been a lot of research suggesting it's neither predictive nor does it add any extra value compared to other satisfaction survey. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_Promoter#Criticism_of_NPS

Comment: @nightning every popular system has detractors. It doesn't take away from the fact that it's a simple one question check that has been shown to correlate directly with other well-respected methods (like SUS and satisfaction index). If you want more detail, you include more questions, but the NPS number is still a reasonable trend to watch.

Answer (score 1):

## Your net is too wide

An internet average would be totally useless. That's like asking how your income compares to the global average. That wouldn't give you much insight into your quality of life in San Francisco, for instance.

## Analyze the competition

What you want is a reference against a competitive set or some other target set. The type of business or content you're in will significantly influence your NPS.

NPS is a reasonable high-level indicator of how users feel about a given experience. But the number itself has to be viewed relative to the historical trend for that site and the space in which it operates.

I've worked on sites that were hovering in the mid to high 80s, but actually had more UX issues than others sitting down in the 60s. The product, business model, demographics, and other factors are all represented in that number.

## NPS is a really broad indicator

As an indicator of overall sentiment, NPS will include many factors that UX can not impact. That's okay, you can still influence the total with UX improvement. But don't expect UX alone to ever get you to 100. For the record, I've never seen a 100 ;-)